# How to insert new datagridview row in datagridview and update (automatically) in database?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datagridview, insert

In this case I display values into datagridview from Projects table which it has only 2 columns:

```
PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR
ID INT // Which is hidden in datagridview, and as AUTOINCREMENT
```

I have already done with editing values in this table and it works fine:

```
private void dataGridView4_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
       {
           string name_project = dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
           string id = dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

           MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ");
           MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE projekt1.projects SET PROJECTS_NAME = @PROJECTS_NAME WHERE ID = @ID", connection);

           cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = int.Parse(id);
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROJECTS_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name_project;

           try
           {
               connection.Open();
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               connection.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
       }
```

But i have a problem with inserting new row and saving automatically in database.

**What i've tried?**

1) I've tried with `RowValidated` Event:

```
private void dataGridView4_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
     {
         string name_project = dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
         string id = dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

         MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ");
         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO projekt1.projects(PROJECT_NAME) VALUES(@NPROJECT_NAME);", connection);

         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = int.Parse(id);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROJECT_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name_project;

         try
         {
             connection.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             connection.Close();

             MessageBox.Show("ok");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }

         try
         {
             connection.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             connection.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
```

But it didn't work because of

> System.FormatException: "Invalid input string format."

2) I've tried that `UserAddedRow` event too:

```
private void dataGridView4_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            string name_project= e.Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            int id = (int)Convert.ToInt64(e.Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO projekt1.projects(PROJECT_NAME) VALUES(@NPROJECT_NAME);", connection);


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = id;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROJECT_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name_project;


            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("ok");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

but then have that exception in below:

> System.NullReferenceException: The object reference has not been set
>   to the instance of the object.
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.”

Then i tried removing 2 lines of code:

```
int id = (int)Convert.ToInt64(e.Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = id;
```

And it didn't help.

Can someone please write how to solve it? I've searched something but i don't know how to deal with. Greetings.

Comment: space is missing in table name and column name `INSERT INTO projekt1.projects (PROJECT_NAME) VALUES (@NPROJECT_NAME);`  .if not work then on which line error occured

Comment: There is no *need* to manually update the db.  Using a DataSource, a DataAdapter  will do it for you.  Another way would be by using an ORM.  None of that code is needed using either of them.

Comment: @MangeshAuti i don't think that is about missing table name and column name, because is about System.NullReferenceException: "The object reference has not been set to the instance of the object.". And it shows at line: `string name_project= e.Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();`

Comment: what about first aproach ?on which line error came

Comment: What kind of aproach? with `RowValidated`? Me thinks that is only when i update value on some ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ShowNewButtonInHeader` property

```
<Columns>
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButtonInHeader="true </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
</Columns>
```

Comment: maybe, but i use windows forms application. Not asp.net.